# Html5 attribute maxlength="5" gets useless after changing event.keyCode

Tags: html, jquery, keycode

I got an input field for captcha which prevents user from typing non Ascii code in it:

```
<input id="Captcha" asp-for="@Model.item.CaptchaCode" type="text" class="noFarsi" maxlength="5" placeholder="ُHuman Code" autocomplete="off" />
```

and the related class to prevent from typing Farsi(Persian) :

```
$(".noFarsi").keypress(function (e) {
   var keyCode = e.which;
   if (keyCode >= 127) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

It was working correctly till I decided to add some new feature. The following class converts non English inputs to English :

```
$(".convertToEnglish").keydown(function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.which;                
            switch (keyCode) {
                case 65: typeFunc("A", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 66: typeFunc("B", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 67: typeFunc("C", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 68: typeFunc("D", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 69: typeFunc("E", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 70: typeFunc("F", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 71: typeFunc("G", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 72: typeFunc("H", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 73: typeFunc("I", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 74: typeFunc("J", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 75: typeFunc("K", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 76: typeFunc("L", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 77: typeFunc("M", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 78: typeFunc("N", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 79: typeFunc("O", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 80: typeFunc("P", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 81: typeFunc("Q", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 82: typeFunc("R", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 83: typeFunc("S", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 84: typeFunc("T", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 85: typeFunc("U", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 86: typeFunc("V", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 87: typeFunc("W", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 88: typeFunc("X", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 89: typeFunc("Y", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 90: typeFunc("Z", e, e.target.id); break;
            }
        });




   function typeFunc(str, e, thisID) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#" + thisID).val($("#" + thisID).val() + str);
      }
```

With the recent changes, and adding `convertToEnglish` to my Captcha input fields, when the user input language is Eng or Farsi, it doesn't matter :) and the field text fills correctly in English, but the max-length attribute becomes useless and the user can type 10 or many characters in my captcha field. Any help is appreciated.

I tried using `keypress` and Unicode codes but no still the same problem:

```
            $(".convertToEnglish").keypress(function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode;
            switch (keyCode) {
                case 1588: typeFunc("A", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 1584: typeFunc("B", e, e.target.id); break;
                case 1586: typeFunc("C", e, e.target.id); break;                
                // some similar codes here
            }
        });
```

Another point : the input field prevents from typing more than 5 digital character : I can type "12345ABCDEFG" but I'm not allowed to type "123456ABCDEFG"

Comment: If you are manually setting the contents or prevent default, the task falls on you to limit the amount of characters - any attribute rules on a node don't actually get followed if you fill the node with `node.value = 'whatever'`. Wouldn't it be better to use the inputs `pattern` attribute and limit it to `//[A-Za-z0-9]` or something?

Comment: Yes, I made all the limitations by RegEx too, but I wonder if I can change the input language somehow. If possible,

Comment: I'm not sure. I am wondering what problem you are trying to solve here - is farsi an issue? Isn't a captcha something you will just match? And if it's farsi it won't match? Has it got to do with potential confusion between the two languages and their characters for users? For a quick solution to your `max-length` issue, just try `event.target.value = event.target.value.slice(5)` at the end of your event listener.

Comment: Users fill all the fields in my form in Farsi and press `Tab` button on keyboard, and start typing in Captcha filed , and then head up and see Wow !! nothing typed in captcha or Farsi typed and have to delete the field type again. I'm  looking for convenient ... Your java script code it useful. thanks

Comment: You could also just regex away at it in that fashion: `event.target.value = event.target.value.replace( /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '' ).slice( 5 )` which would remove _any_ foreign characters and limit your string to 5? (Regex: replace everything NOT english with nothing)

Comment: Also, correction: `slice` should be `slice(0,5)`, my bad. Otherwise it would _start_ at character 5, leaving it empty.

Answer (score 0):

If preventing anything that should't be typed into the text field is the goal, maybe it can be accomplished in a much simpler way:

```
event.target.value = event.target.value.replace( /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '' ).slice(0, 5);
```

This limits the characters you can enter to A-Z, a-z and 0-9, and imposes a max-length.

```js
document.querySelector( '#input' ).addEventListener( 'input', event => {
  
  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace( /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '' ).slice(0, 5);
  
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
```